# Display text and/or image instead of database result

Tags: php, mysql, database, url

As I am very new to MySQL and PHP, I ask for tips to solve the following.

I like to show a result (*description*) based on a form request as **text** (by example '*read more*') or an image, instead of the url which is stored in the database.

```
<?php
function description_link($description) {
    return '<a href="http://www.******/' . $description . '">' . $description . '</a>';
}
?>

<DIV DATA-BINDING-ID="repeat" DATA-BINDING-REPEAT="{{allpubsExecutor.data.allpubs}}">
    <SPAN DATA-BINDING-SHOW="{{description !=""}}"><?php echo description_link('{{description}}'); ?></SPAN>
</DIV>
```

I am using **DMXzone Server Connect.**
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but you want to link text as `read more` I think so change your function to

```
<?php
function description_link($description) {
    return '<a href="http://www.******/' . $description . '">' . "Read more" . '</a>'; //<--------change this add read more
}
?>

<DIV DATA-BINDING-ID="repeat" DATA-BINDING-REPEAT="{{allpubsExecutor.data.allpubs}}">
    <SPAN DATA-BINDING-SHOW="{{description !=""}}"><?php echo description_link('{{description}}'); ?></SPAN>
</DIV>
```

Comment: I already tried this solution, without success as the text "Read more" is displayed in all results, and 

    DATA-BINDING-SHOW="{{description !=""}}" 

is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You are using server connect along with the dmxDatabindings right?
The code you posted will not work. You should use something like this:

```
<DIV DATA-BINDING-ID="repeat" DATA-BINDING-REPEAT={{allpubsExecutor.data.allpubs}}"><SPAN DATA-BINDING-SHOW="{{description}}"><a href="{{urlLink}}"><img src="" data-binding-src="{{image_binding}}" /></a>
```

If you like to use a `read more text` link, use the following:

```
<DIV DATA-BINDING-ID="repeat" DATA-BINDING-REPEAT="{{allpubsExecutor.data.allpubs}}"><SPAN DATA-BINDING-SHOW="{{description}}"><a href="{{urlLink}}">Read More</a></SPAN></DIV>
```

Hope this helps.
Thank you